# Discord.Py change what channel message goes in

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

TOKEN = 'My Token'
command_prefix = '='
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix = command_prefix)
announcement_channel_set = ""
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
  print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(bot))

@bot.command()
async def announcement(announcement_channel_set, announcement_text):
  if announcement_channel_set == "":
    await bot.send(f"@everyone {announcement_text}")
  else:
    channel = announcement_channel_set
    await channel.send(f"@everyone {announcement_text}")
@bot.command()
async def changeannouncementchannel(ctx, change: discord.TextChannel):
  global announcement_channel_set
  announcement_channel_set = bot.get_channel(change)
  await ctx.send(f"Announcement Channel Changed To #{change}")


bot.run(TOKEN)
```

This is my whole program, what I don't get is why when I change announcement_channel_set as a global variable, it doesn't change the channel I want the announcement to go into when I do =announcement {message}

Answer (score 2):

You have a couple things a bit off with your code.

###### Problem #1

In your function `announcement`, what you do if `announcement_channel_set == ""` is you use `bot.send`, which does not work in the discord.py rewrite. We need to change the first parameter in the function to be `ctx` and not `announcement_channel_set`.

###### Problem #2

In your 2nd function `changeannouncementchannel`, you already type hint `change` to be an instance of `discord.TextChannel`, so you don't need to do the function `bot.get_channel(change)`, instead just `change`.

###### Other Changes

I changed `announcement_channel_set` to a bot variable, so we don't have to use global.

I used `change.mention` instead of `#{change}` so that it mentions the channel and the blue text appears.

#### Code

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

TOKEN = 'My Token'
command_prefix = '='
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix = command_prefix)
bot.announcement_channel = ""

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
  print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(bot))

@bot.command()
async def announcement(ctx, announcement_text):
  if bot.announcement_channel == "":
    await ctx.send(f"@everyone {announcement_text}")
  else:
    await bot.announcement_channel.send(f"@everyone {announcement_text}")

@bot.command()
async def changeannouncementchannel(ctx, change: discord.TextChannel):
  bot.announcement_channel = change
  await ctx.send(f"Announcement Channel Changed To {change.mention}")
```

Answer (score 0):

When we're coding, we don't typically use [`global variables`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-global-statement), they cause issues and are generally difficult to manage. Rather, you can use a [`class`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html) with assigned [`properties`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property) that you can access from anywhere in your code. I've re-written parts of your code to adjust for these suggestions that will hopefully help you down the road.

```py
import discord

class Announcement_Channel:
    @property
    def channel(self):
        return self._channel

    def __init__(self, channel):
        self._channel = channel

announcement_channel = Announcement_Channel(None)

@bot.command()
async def announcement(ctx, announcement_text):
    if announcement_channel.channel is None:
        await ctx.send(f"@everyone {announcement_text}")
    else:
        await announcement_channel.channel.send(f"@everyone {announcement_text}")

@bot.command()
async def set_announcement_channel(ctx, channel: discord.TextChannel):
    announcement_channel._channel = channel
    await ctx.send(f"Announcement Channel Changed To {channel.mention}")
```